# How to calculate cumulative return with pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I calculate cumulative return of portfolio, with daily return?

```
                    Return  Portfolio
1999-01-04             NaN        100
1999-01-05        0.011430        100
1999-01-06        0.024109        100
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
df['Portfolio'] = df.shift(1)['Portfolio'] * (1 + df['Return'])
```

I want to get 100, 101.14, 103.5 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html), but you would need to add `1` to the returns:

```
df.Return.fillna(0).add(1).cumprod() * df['Portfolio']
```

Output:

```
1999-01-04    100.000000
1999-01-05    101.143000
1999-01-06    103.581457
dtype: float64
```